# Hateoas links upends "&amp;" in the link between query parameters

Tags: java

Below code produces Hateoas link as

```
//IP/api/bs/bookings?firstname=FRANK&amp;familyname=BEN&amp;destination=EDI

myResource.add(
    linkTo(
         methodOn(myController.class).getMymethod(
             firstName,
             familyName,
              identifierType, 
              token,
              flightNumber, 
              destination,
              issuingCountry,
              headerValueMap
         )
    )
    .withSelfRel()
    .expand()
);
```

However if i print the same in SOP then it prints as

```
//IP/api/bs/bookings?firstname=FRANK&familyname=BEN&destination=EDI
```

This is correct one but when I get this in JSON in POSTMAN I get this link with `&amp;`.

Method return type is `Application/JSON`.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.